# How to do something when a component has received props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react-router app that mounts `User` on `/users`. It works fine.

I then click a `/users?page=2` link that passes in new props. Here `getData` uses `this.props.location.query`. So calling getData from componentWillReceiveProps will fetch stuff from page 1 instead of page 2.

I would have used component**HasReceived**Props method if it existed. What can I actually do?

```
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.setState({data:null});
    this.getData();
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    this.setState({data:null});
    this.getData();
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things.

1) Using `this.setState` synchronously inside `componentWillMount` works, but serves no purpose since you might as well have just done this inside of `getInitialState` instead.

2) If you want to react to props changes like this, you need to use the `nextProps` object inside `componentWillreceiveProps`.  A simple fix is to change your `getData` method to allow the passing of `nextProps` to it.  Such as:

```
getData: function(nextProps) {
  var props = nextProps || this.props;

  // your getData stuff
}
```

And then pass it in your `componentWillReceiveProps` method as `this.getData(nextProps)`.